# Computing closest cluster for a set of points

Tags: performance, matlab, classification

I have a problem where I have a list of cluster centers and a list of points for which I have to get the closest cluster.

Eg:

```
nclusters = 10;
npoints = 100;
% Generate 10 random clusters in a 2D space
Clusters = rand(nclusters,2);
% Generate 100 random points in a 2D space
Points = rand(npoints,2);

% plot them
figure(1), hold on
plot(Clusters(:,1), Clusters(:,2), 'ro')
plot(Points(:,1), Points(:,2), 'bx')
```

[image]

Now I can iterate over each point and calculate which cluster is the closest one:

```
  ClusterIndexes = zeros(npoints,1) 
  for i = 1:npoints
      % sum of squared differences (square root can be avoided)
      SquareDist = sum(bsxfun(@minus, Clusters, Points(i,:)).^2, 2);
      % Index of the closest cluster
      [minVal minIdx] = min(SquareDist);
      ClusterIndexes(i) = minIdx;  
  end

  % plot results
  figure(2), hold on
  plot(Clusters(:,1), Clusters(:,2), 'ro')
  plot(Points(:,1), Points(:,2), 'bx')
  plot([Points(:,1) Clusters(ClusterIndexes,1)]', [Points(:,2) Clusters(ClusterIndexes,2)]', 'm-');
```

[image]

This code works and is efficient since I am using `bsxfun`. 
However, is there a better way of doing it? Maybe getting rid of the loop?

I am thinking in a case where there is a huge number of points and they might be in a high dimensional space.

Thanks

Comment: It may be more efficient to loop over the clusters instead of the points, as there are fewer of these.

Comment: Mmmm I don't see how this will work. For the current cluster I'll get the distance to all points and compute the closest point to the cluster. But I'll need to store this distance matrices over the loops. I think it will require more memory and more operations.
Also it is not guaranteed that the number of clusters is lower that the number of points. In the question I just used a toy example.